# 'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'businessLabel'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am encountering a strange error while trying to configure a prototype cell for use with a couple of arrays. I have set up a table view controller that is governed by 'BDTableViewController', and contains one prototype cell which is governed by the class 'BDTableViewCell'. However, Xcode is complaining that

> 'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'businessLabel'

when the businessLabel outlet is clearly linked up to my BDTableViewCell. Included are the files themselves. Any idea as to what is going wrong?

[image]

BDTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class BDTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {


var BusinessNameArray = [String]()
var BusinessLogoArray = [String]()
var BusinessAddressArray = [String]()
var BusinessNumberArray = [String]()
var BusinessWebsiteArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    BusinessNameArray = ["Premiere Dance"]
    BusinessLogoArray = ["PD.tiff"]
    BusinessAddressArray = ["30 Brower Lane, Hillsborough, NJ 08844"]
    BusinessNumberArray = ["(908) 281-9442"]
    BusinessWebsiteArray = ["http://premieredancenj.com/"]


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return BusinessNameArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    let item = BusinessNameArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.businessLabel.text = item




    return cell
}
}
```

BDTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

[![enter image description here][1]][1]class BDTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var businessLogo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var businessLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var businessAddress: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var businessPhone: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var businessWebsite: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this line

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
```

you let the compiler know that `cell` is (just) a `UITableViewCell`, but a regular `UITableViewCell` doens't have a property called `businessLabel`. When you change the line to

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! BDTableViewCell
```

the code will compile.

Comment: And make sure you've got `BDTableViewCell` specified in the attributes inspector of the prototype cell.

Comment: @AdrianB if that wasn't the case, he wouldn't be able to connect the outlets in the storyboard.